# How to delete a post on facebook using a delete button link

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to delete a post like a photo on Facebook using delete button link. I'm using Python.

In url, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/, I found below,

> You can delete a post as long as your application created the post. You delete a post by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to the POST_ID object with publish_stream permission.

So my application can't directly delete a post.

Can my application delete a post using delete button link? For example, using "Delete This Photo" button in Timeline Photos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I undrestand correctly, but as you said and is stated in the Graph API docs, it's only possible to delete Posts your app has created. Deleting Posts from other apps is denied from the Graph API.